# Loader doesn't stop adding views to list items when scrolling up and down

Tags: android, android-listview, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I try to load ListView items with a custom CursorLoader into a list. The problem is, if I scroll to the bottom and up again Android adds multiple **new images** to every list item. My question is, how to prevent Android to load more images into the list.
Column 1 should always have only one image, column 2 two images...

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private Context mCtx       = null;
private MyAdapter mAdapter = null;

private final static String COLUMN_A = "a";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCtx     = this;
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mCtx);

    ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview)).setAdapter(mAdapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loader_id, Bundle bundle) {

    return new MyCursorLoader(mCtx) {

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            MatrixCursor m = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", COLUMN_A});
            m.addRow(new String[]{"1", "Column 1"});
            m.addRow(new String[]{"2", "Column 2"});
            m.addRow(new String[]{"3", "Column 3"});
            m.addRow(new String[]{"4", "Column 4"});
            m.addRow(new String[]{"5", "Column 5"});
            return m;
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
}


private class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter(final Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, null, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View v, final Context ctx, final Cursor c) {
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) v;
        final int position = c.getPosition();

        Log.i("MyAdapter", "Cursor position: "+ position
                + "\tImages: "+ (parent.getChildCount() -1));

        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.content))
            .setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_A)));


        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(ctx);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i=0; i<(position+1); i++) {
            SystemClock.sleep(i * 100);
            ImageView img = new ImageView(ctx);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            ll.addView(img);
        }

        parent.addView(ll);
    }
}


private abstract class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

    public MyCursorLoader(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public abstract Cursor loadInBackground();
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:text="---"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

**↓ after trying Diogo Bento suggestion on a Galaxy S1:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is not an efficient solution, but you can remove the `LinearLayout`. an efficient solution is to check if the `LinearLayout` has the number of `childs` different to the position and add or remove the images to get the number of images that you want.

```
**parent.removeViewAt(1);**
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(ctx);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 for (int i=0; i<(position+1); i++) {
        SystemClock.sleep(i * 100);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(ctx);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ll.addView(img);
 }
parent.addView(ll);
```

Comment: The idea to remove all views from the LinearLayout if the child count is not equal 'position' works for the above example → with the downside that scrolling is jerky (data cashing is not possible). Now I don't know what to do, your answer works, but is not really usable.

Comment: try the other option. check the number of images against the position and add or remove images to match that position. you probably just have to add one image or remove one image, so the efficiency is way better.

Comment: Your suggestion works. The code in the above question is just test code to illustrate a problem I have in a bigger project. There date comes from a DB and everything is a bit more complicated (I don't add a single Layout with some icons - I add different widgets). My next try is to split the code more, and make so to say every single image a ListView row. I accept your answer, because it works.

Comment: i don't know the nature of your problem, but one way to implement a image cache is using the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void bindView(final View v, final Context ctx, final Cursor c) {
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) v;
final int position = c.getPosition();

Log.i("MyAdapter", "Cursor position: "+ position
        + "\tImages: "+ (parent.getChildCount() -1));

((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.content))
    .setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_A)));
//use a linear layout defined in the item.xml instead of dynamically create one
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
for (int i=0; i<(position+1); i++) {
    SystemClock.sleep(i * 100);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(ctx);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    //assign an id to the image to add
    int id = i+10000;
    img.setId(id);
    //check if the image has been already added.
    if(ll.findViewById(id) == null){
        ll.addView(img);
    }
}
```

}

**item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:text="---"/>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

you can of course skip the creation of the image and the sleep on next scrolling if you slightly change the for loop like this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<(position+1); i++) {
        int id = i+10000;
    //check if the image has been already added.
    if(ll.findViewById(id) == null){ 
        SystemClock.sleep(i * 100);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(ctx);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        //assign an id to the image to add
        img.setId(id);
        ll.addView(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, sadly it doesn't solve the problem → video: http://ubuntuone.com/3XhT92Qm6RKxMwSD1jyDeS

Comment: I'm like going crazy about this problem... Now I'm moving away from using LoaderManager and ListView to a LinearLayout + Adapter and loading my ViewGroups in AsyncTasks. It's not how it should be, but it works.

Comment: Ah, the problem occurs when using API 7 and the android support library v4.